Snowflake Put Statement Fails with Lock Exceeds Error
I have an ETL pipeline that consists of multiple concurrent writes to Snowflake via the PUT and COPY INTO commands.  The PUT command successfully uploads my files into the appropriate TABLE STAGE in Snowflake, however the COPY INTO command I run to load the newly staged data into the actual tables fails with the following error message:
Your statement  was aborted because the number of waiters for this lock exceeds the 20 statements limit.. What's the best way to resolve this issue?

@brandon, I like your approach using tasks for table locking while inserting.
You can take this step by using Snowflake Pipes to load from the internal stage. CREATE PIPE docs
This way, multiple processes can put files through an internal stage, and Snowflake PIPE will insert data into tables. This approach should have lower latency than the task approach.
CREATE PIPE mypipe2
  AS
  COPY INTO mytable(C1, C2)
  FROM (SELECT $5, $4 FROM @mystage)
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'JSON');


Thanks @neeru0303! I think this is absolutely the way to go when ingesting data from S3, where there's already a mechanism to trigger the pipe.  In my case, I was loading data from EFS via Python and didn't want to bother having to integrate with the Snowflake API in order to trigger the pipe... with the task based approached, I could simply execute the task with my existing connection.  That being said, what are your thoughts?

Since the task is executed after the put statements, only one task can run at a time, which might cause some latency issues. With Snowflake pipe, Snowflake will concurrently file as the PUT operations are completed. SnowPipe might be costlier than Tasks running on a user-managed warehouse because charges are a little more for system-defined warehouses.  We need to think about trade-offs b/w the cost and latency.

Create a Snowflake TASK to execute the COPY INTO command and execute that task from your process.  This runs the COPY INTO commands serially as needed, eliminating the concurrency issue.  Per the EXECUTE TASK documentation:

Snowflake ensures only one instance of a task with a schedule is executed at a time.
If the root task is currently running (i.e. in an EXECUTING state in the TASK_HISTORY output), the EXECUTE TASK command schedules another run of the task to start immediately after the current run is completed.
If the root task is currently scheduled (i.e. in a SCHEDULED state in the TASK_HISTORY output), the scheduled run is replaced with the requested run as usual, with the current timestamp as the scheduled time. However, if the scheduled time has passed (but the task has not yet transitioned to an EXECUTING state), then the scheduled run occurs as usual. That is, the scheduled run is not replaced with the requested run.

